# Lock Extended Cost

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

How can extended cost be locked, so that it cannot be keyed over?  Currently, a qty and a unit cost calculate, but the extended cost can be changed.
[View of Changed Cost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4K6N.png)

Answer (score 1):

Create a graph extension for POOrderEntry (I am assuming this is the PO Order Screen)

Add a cache attached handler as follows:

```
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Ext. Cost", Enabled = false)]
[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Merge)]
protected virtual void _(Events.CacheAttached<POLine.curyExtCost> e)
{
}
```